# Can you destroy a space station in No Man's Sky?

Tags: no-mans-sky

Can you destroy a space station in No Man's Sky? I was wondering because shooting the station causes sentinels to attack you as if you were attacking another starship, freighter or freighter cargo pods.

Answer (score 5):

No, [Space Stations](https://nomanssky.gamepedia.com/Space_station#Attacking) cannot be destroyed

> **While you can attack a station, it cannot actually be destroyed**. If attacked long enough, eventually Sentinel starships will attack you.
>
> As an integral part of the game, it will always remain in orbit around its host star system.
>
> <sub>(emphasis my own)</sub>